# I need the background image to occupy 100% height and width of the div without cutting the border from it

Tags: javascript, html, css

[When it wraps to a new line, I still need it to occupy 100% of the container.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXf1R.png)
[need to occupy 100% width am height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svylu.png)

If I could manually set this border, it might be a solution, but it's not accepted.

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 207px;
}

.pil1 {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 600px;
    border-top-left-radius: 104px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 104px;
    background-image: url("../images/backgrounds/main_banner_bg_left.svg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.pil2 {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 600px;
    border-top-right-radius: 104px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 104px;
    background-image: url("../images/backgrounds/main_banner_bg_right.svg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .flex {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 20px;
    }

    .pil1 {
        /* height: 100%; */
        width: 600px;
        border-radius: 104px;
        background-image: url("../images/backgrounds/main_banner_bg_mobile.svg");
        background-size: auto 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }

    .pil2 {
        /* height: 100%; */
        border-radius: 104px;
        background-image: url("../images/backgrounds/main_banner_bg_mobile.svg");
        background-size: auto 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
}

<div class="container-fluid container_first">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="pil1">
                <h1>Content</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="pil2">
                <h1>content</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

a solution would be if I could put this border manually, but it is not received